# JPA OneToMany with same entity using JoinTable

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, liquibase

I have a OneToMany relationship that I need to model in JPA. I have a class called CustomerItem that needs to have certain CustomerItems (list) related to it. Therefore, I modeled it using JoinTable to keep this in a separate table.

I've tried to model it like this:

```
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "mp_related_item", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_item_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
           private Set<CustomerItem> relatedItems;
```

I've created my table using Liquibase:

```
<createTable tableName="MP_RELATED_ITEM">
        <column autoIncrement="true" name="ID" type="BIGINT">
            <constraints primaryKey="true"
                primaryKeyName="PK_MP_RELATED_ITEMS" />
        </column>
        <column name="CUSTOMER_ITEM_ID" type="BIGINT" />
        <column name="RELATED_ITEM_ID" type="BIGINT" />
</createTable>
```

However, this results in an exception when trying to load relatedItems for a specific CustomerItem:

```
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Ogiltigt kolumnnamn, 'relatedItems_ID'. (Illegal column name)
```

What am I doing wrong here? When I check the generated query it seems like the persistence framework thinks that relatedItems is one single entity, when in reality it's a list of multiple entities that I want to load.

Comment: Why do you use a join table? A FK on the Customer table would be enough

Comment: There's no customer table here, only a CustomerItem table (and the join table). @SimonMartinelli

Comment: Yes sorry I mean CustomerItem.

Comment: How would that even work, having a FK on the same table? I thought JoinTable was the only way to go here, could you describe it a bit more in detail? @SimonMartinelli

Comment: No you just add the FK on the same table

Comment: Join Tables are only need for ManyToMany

Comment: But would this not result in a lot of duplicated data? One customer item having multiple customerItems as relatedItems -> many identical rows with only the one field "related_item" being different? That's why I opted for the Jointable, so that table only modelled the relationship customerItem - relatedItems. I might be missing something here. @SimonMartinelli

Comment: Then I didn't understand you model. Can you please describe how the classes are releated

Comment: There should be no duplicated data if this is true One to many, as that usually implies the other side is Many to one: the list of relatedItems can only have 1 parent CustomerItem, so is fine with a FK for the relationship. If they can have more than one, it is a manyTomany. Regardless, the join table is fine - I've used it for 1:1s in some situations. The problem here is just that you defined the joinColumns but not the inverseJoinColumns, forcing JPA to default to relatedItems_ID as the fk instead of "RELATED_ITEM_ID"

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the explanation, this solved my issue.